# Angular 5 callback and that=this

Tags: javascript, angular, callback, this

in my Angular 5 project I have some problems with the callback from an external library. I load it using

```
<script src="https://js.chargebee.com/v2/chargebee.js" data-cb-site="my-site"> </script>
```

and then in Angular I import it as follows:

```
declare var Chargebee: any;
Chargebee.init({site: "my-site"});
```

I also have a public variable in my component, lets say `publicVar`, which I am displaying in the template.

```
publicVar: string = 'before checkout';
```

I have the following method:

```
subscribeToPlan() {
  var _self = this;
  var chargebeeInstance = Chargebee.getInstance();

  chargebeeInstance.openCheckout({
    hostedPage: function() {
      _self.publicVar = 'hosted-page';
      console.log('hosted-page');
    },
    success: function(hostedPageId) {
      _self.publicVar = 'success';
      console.log('success');
    },
    close: function() {
      _self.publicVar = 'closed';
      console.log('closed');
    }
  });
}
```

What is happening when I run the code?

All the `console.log` functions output the correct data, so I know the chargebee callbacks are called. However, only `hostedPage: function() {}` correctly changes my `publicVar`, and it says "hosted-page" in my template.

`success: function(){}` nor `close: function(){}` won't update the `publicVar` in my template. I suspect because these are, unlike the  `hostedPage`, a callback methods and the `self.` in them has wrong context?

Comment: Have you dropped in a breakpoint and checked what `_self` is?

Comment: yes, `_self` has everything it should have and it is in fact my component, but even doing `_self.publicVar='test'` in the console won't update the template in `success` and `close` methods

Answer (score 2):

So I worked it out (or found a workaround)

As the `_self` did hold the correct data, I thought that the change detection is not triggered for those callbacks. After I've manually triggered it, it all works as expected.

Final code and changes:

Import

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
```

Add it to the constructor:

```
constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef)
```

And then call it at the end of the callback method, this will manually trigger Angular change detection, and updates template rendering of `publicVar`

```
subscribeToPlan() {
  var _self = this;
  var chargebeeInstance = Chargebee.getInstance();

  chargebeeInstance.openCheckout({
    hostedPage: function() {
      _self.publicVar = 'hosted-page';  // This is not a callback, so it just works
      console.log('hosted-page');
    },
    success: function(hostedPageId) {
      console.log('success');
      _self.publicVar = 'success';
      _self.cd.detectChanges();  // Manual change detection
    },
    close: function() {
      console.log('closed');
      _self.publicVar = 'closed';
      _self.cd.detectChanges();  // Manual change detection
    }
  });
}
```

Alternative code using the arrow functions, as per Joe's suggestion (https://stackoverflow.com/a/50335020/5644425)

```
subscribeToPlan() {
  var chargebeeInstance = Chargebee.getInstance();

  chargebeeInstance.openCheckout({
    hostedPage: () => {
      this.publicVar = 'hosted-page';
      console.log('hosted-page');
    },
    success: hostedPageId => {
      console.log('success');
      this.publicVar = 'success';
      this.cd.detectChanges();
    },
    close: () => {
      console.log('closed');
      this.publicVar = 'closed';
      this.cd.detectChanges();
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: That's strange, have you changed the `ChangeDetectionStrategy` to `OnPush` or something?

Comment: I haven't (intentionally) overridden any default behaviour

Answer (score 1):

Rather than assigning this to some variable `_self` you could just use arrow functions, which don't affect the scope of `this`:

```
subscribeToPlan() {
  var chargebeeInstance = Chargebee.getInstance();

  chargebeeInstance.openCheckout({
    hostedPage: () => {
      this.publicVar = 'hosted-page';
      console.log('hosted-page');
    },
    success: hostedPageId => {
      this.publicVar = 'success';
      console.log('success');
    },
    close: () => {
      this.publicVar = 'closed';
      console.log('closed');
    }
  });
}
```

And without the logging this becomes the even neater:

```
subscribeToPlan() {
  var chargebeeInstance = Chargebee.getInstance();

  chargebeeInstance.openCheckout({
    hostedPage: () => this.publicVar = 'hosted-page',
    success: hostedPageId => this.publicVar = 'success',
    close: () => this.publicVar = 'closed'
  });
}
```

Though I think your code should work fine. You're assigning `this` to `_self` and using that, so the `this` of the functions shouldn't matter. I'd definitely recommend putting in a breakpoint and checking what `_self` is in those two functions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but unfortunately, this works exactly like my example. console.log works, but the template var is only updated in hostedPage() function, not success and close callbacks :(

Comment: Worked for me actually. Changed from:
`service.request(url, this.update)`
to:
`service.request(url, ()=> this.update())`
And worked fine. Inside update function this refers to component object